# Does a Van de Graaff generator store charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

I am was reading some answers on whether capacitors store charge (which they don't, as far as I know), on this website, and then one response got me thinking:

> There are some ways to store or accumulate static electric charge.
>   A [Van de Graaff generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator)
>   is a device that accumulates electric charge. This can actually store a net charge. This device stores excess charge with respect to ground and touching it makes your hair stand up.

Still, this device with respect to itself should be neutral and so stores no net charge, so my question is, does Van de Graaff generator really store charge, or is it like a capacitor?

Answer (score 2):

The dome of a Van de Graaff generator can be thought of as an "isolated" conducting sphere of [capacitance](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html) $C=4 \pi \epsilon_0 R$ where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and the other plate is the earth.
The charge is stored on the outside of the sphere.

Comment: so, this means a Van de Graff doesn't store charge also, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: The VdG stores charge on its dome.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitors store equal and opposite charges on their plates. Even so, engineers and most physicists do talk (knowing what they mean) about capacitors storing charge. A few pedants like me qualify this by saying that the net charge stored is zero. The sphere of a V de G is, effectively, one 'plate' of a capacitor. Its surroundings form the other 'plate'.

Comment: still, this does not explain the point I am talking about, can a V de G gen and  a capacitor be like the same thing?

Comment: Doesn't my last sentence answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes, a Van de Graaff generator does store charge.

Longer Answer: The charge stored in a VdG is electrostatic; this means it is a localized charge imbalance where electrons have either accumulated to outnumber protons on the conductive sphere, or been pulled out of the sphere to leave it with net positive charge.

The net charge is typically very small; micro-Coulombs or less, because as more charge is added, the voltage gets so high that it induces either breakdown (a spark through the air to a nearby object neutralizing the charge on the sphere) or corona effects (bleeding charge into the air itself by ionizing a few air molecules).

This is different from how a capacitor works; a capacitor typically functions based on an image charge.  You raise one plate to a potential, positive or negative voltage, and the other plate matches the potential with the same number of charges of the opposite sign.  This happens because the electric field from the first plate creates a mirror image of itself on the second by pulling charges of opposite sign as close as possible. The charges accumulated then release when the potential is removed, feeding charge back into the conductors they followed to get there.  The whole system is essentially neutral and balanced; no net electric fields outside the system.

Contrast this with the VdG generator (for the example, consider a positively charged one).  You have a conveyor belt that literally strips electrons out of the electrode and carries them down to a grounded circuit.  The electrons flow to ground.  The electrode is electrically isolated from anything that can conduct its positive charge away, so it remains charged.  You end up with an unbalanced system, and a strong positive electric field extending far from the electrode.

It's sort of like if you built a plate capacitor, charged it, then cut the wire to one end so it could not discharge, peeled the plates apart, and grounded the plate with the wire still connected.  On the plate with the cut wire you would have a floating electrode with charge of only one sign.